# Exporting PDF created using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I'm using the JavaScript library, jsPDF, to create and save a PDF created from a table in a HTML document. What I need to do is be able to pass the PDF that was created to another function so that I can send it as an email attachment. How do I capture the file in a variable? The docs don't really say how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send generated PDF to server first so that you can attach the PDF to an Email. You can send the pdf to the server as a base64 string.

Later, You can convert the base64 string to PDF in any Server Side Language like PHP, Java, C#, Python etc. & email it as an attachment.